# iPod - How to display the battery remaining as a percentage?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, battery

How can I display the remaining battery power as a percentage on an iPod Touch 5.

Answer (score 2):

That's an option to enable :

```
Settings > General > Usage > Battery Percentage
```

Comment: This is wrong. The iPod touch doesn't have a "battery percentage" control with stock iOS.